# iOS sqlite insert statments with variables

Tags: ios, sqlite, insert

I am learning how to use sqlite in IOS

I am using the following to insert a record into a table

```
 int DBID =  [_db  ExecuteINSERT:@"INSERT INTO LOG(NAME , COMPANY , CATEGORY)   VALUES('txt1','txt2','txt3')"];
```

This works fine and adds the three strings into a row

I want to exchange the hardcoded strings for string variable but can work out what to do. I tried

```
NSString* myString1 = @"String1";
NSString* myString2 = @"String2";
NSString* myString3 = @"String3";
int DBID = _db  ExecuteINSERT:@"INSERT INTO LOG(NAME , COMPANY,     CATEGORY) VALUES(myString1, myString2, myString3)"];
```

But I get a sqlite error 1 no such column but there is as it works with hardcoded strings

any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Any help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring the same string 3 times, but I will assume that this is just a typo in your question, and what you really have (or at least meant) is:

```
NSString* string1 = @"String1";
NSString* string2 = @"String2";
NSString* string3 = @"String3";
```

Your next problem is that you have included the variable names as literal strings inside the `"` - This means that the SQL statement will contain "string1" not the value of `string1` which is what you are after.

Since you are using a wrapper around SQLite, you can use `stringWithFormat` to create the insert statement with the values of the string variables substituted

```
NSString *sqlStatement=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO LOG(NAME, COMPANY,CATEGORY) values (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",string1,string2,string3];
int DBID = [_db  ExecuteINSERT:sqlStatement];
```

It is worth noting that this is unsafe since you cannot guard against [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) where the values are obtained from user input. This may not be a concern on a mobile device; the worst a user can do is affect their own database.

The technically correct approach if you weren't using a wrapper is to use `sqlite3_prepare_v2`  -

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSString *insertSQL = @"INSERT INTO LOG(NAME, COMPANY,CATEGORY) values (?,?,?)"; 
const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_db, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK) {
    // LOG THE ERROR
    NSLog(@"Error: failed to perpare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(_db));
}
else {
    // Bind values to the statement
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement,1,[string1 UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement,2,[string2 UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_text(statement,3,[string3 UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    double retValue = sqlite3_step(statement);
    if (retValue == SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"Insert successful");
    }
    sqlite3_reset(statement);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

This second block of code creates a statement with three placeholders `(?,?,?)` and then substitutes strings into those placeholders with `sqlite3_bind_text`. Finally, the statement is executed with sqlite3_step.

The last couple of lines just clean up.

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo copy and past at its best. even when I change to three separate string I get the same error your code is just baffling to me I am very new to this and wouldn't no where to start I am using a pre written helper to do this I just can't understand why it works with hardcoded strings and not variable

Comment: It will work using the first code bloc that I showed with the caveat "don't do this".  The second block of code creates a statement with three placeholders (?,?,?) and then substitutes strings into that placeholders with "sqlite3_bind_text" and then finally executes the statement with `sqlite3_step`.  Is there a particular reason you want to use sqlite3? If you aren't developing cross-platform, it is generally much easier to use Core Data.  Although Core Data isn't a relational database, this typically isn't an issue for mobile apps

Comment: I pasted your code into my code and get errors all over the place I don't think I can mix it I am used to using sqlite and use on windows, android etc with no problems very new to IOS just trying not to have a whole new leaning curve when I have something I know works

Comment: If you aren't using sqlite3 you may need to change the calls, but you definitely should look into the documentation for the library you are using to find the right way to prepare sql statements and then bind the values.  This is considered best practice for SQL

Comment: There were a couple of typos I just fixed

Comment: I'm using libsqlite3.0.tbd in Xcode 7.2 and it based on the GITHUB Project EasySQLite by JohnGoodstadt

Comment: Ok, so you are using a wrapper.  This is definitely information you should include in your question. From the looks of that code, I wouldn't use it.  It uses unsafe techniques, but if you aren't too worried about your users entering malicious data (they will only be affecting their own device after all) then use the first bit of code in my answer

Comment: Ok I pasted in and have it down to two errors preventing me running it is there different code for opening the database and closing it as I think thats the problem my database is called "visitor.db" and is in the documents directory of the app

Comment: It looks like you just pass the database file name to `[DBController sharedDatabaseController:dbname]`

Comment: o usually use self.db = [DBController sharedDatabaseController:@"vistorlog.db"];  to open the file but if i then follow it with your code I get errors thee two errors i have are the same  "/Users/markbarr/Documents/Xcode Projects/Visitor pass/Mirror/First.m:102:28: Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'DBController *' to C pointer type 'sqlite3 *' (aka 'struct sqlite3 *') requires a bridged cast"

Comment: No, you can't use my second block of code with the DBController wrapper.  You either need to adopt native sqlite3 or use the first bit of code and accept the risk that a user attempts to mess with their own data

Comment: ok i don't want to get in trouble for extending comments so ill mark as correct one last thing I have the error down to definition of _db in the prepare 2 statement why is that the name of the database or the full path with the name?

Comment: You can see `createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded` in https://github.com/JohnGoodstadt/EasySQLite/blob/master/EasySQLite/DBController.m to see how to copy the database file from the bundle to the documents directory where it can be written and then the `open` function in that same class to see how to get the database reference